# how to use docker-compose start up host docker container with volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i am running docker on windows 10, and have a jenkins container

i can use container jenkins pipeline to build host image

```
docker -H host.docker.internal:2375 tag myproject:1.0 myproject:latest
```

i can start host container use docker-compose

```
docker-compose -H host.docker.internal:2375 -f /var/jenkins_home/myproject/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

the only issue is, if have 'volumes' in docker-compose.yml, it will display error below.

```
Named volume "C:\docker\myproject:/target/myproject" is used in service "myproject" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  myproject:
    image: myproject:latest
    user: root
    container_name: myproject
    volumes:
      - C:\docker\myproject:/target/myproject
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

i understand it is because jenkins container cannot found 'C:\docker\myproject', but i want share this folder between host and myproject container.

i tried use below command in jenkins container but it is not working, -f only can read local container file

```
docker-compose -H host.docker.internal:2375 -f c:/myproject/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

any idea can run docker-compose with volumes in jenkins container to control host docker?

---

update problem solved by below

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  myproject:
    image: myproject:latest
    user: root
    container_name: myproject
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: C:\docker\myproject
        target: /target/myproject
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Comment: You have to declare the volume in the compose file in a separate clause, as shown in the documentation 

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volume-configuration-reference

Comment: @vodbeke I do not think this is the problem, because declaring global `volumes` clause is required only for *named volumes*. OP uses *bind mount* (`host_directory:container_directory`) instead.

Comment: @user14967413 Yes you are right. Instead you should specify the 'source' as the host path and the 'target' as the mount path, like this:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes

Comment: @vodbeke I think volumes declaration should work even with the original short syntax. How about replacing backslashes with forward slashes? But it works even with backslashes on my Docker.

Comment: Jenkins container does not have to know `C:\docker\myproject` path, because only docker daemon on the host uses it, so this shouln't be the problem.

Comment: thank you both, problem solved

Comment: @user14967413 yes, i also think jenkins container no need to check this, but it giving error, not sure windows version problem or what

Comment: Maybe syntax with path relative to compose file would help (`./host_dir/:/container_dir/`) or `//c/host_dir/:/container_dir/` syntax suggested here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3073#issuecomment-262791800

Comment: @user14967413 tried both, able to run without any error, but it is not share between host and container, so it is not working for me